# How can I access local database on react native?

Tags: react-native

We often access a local sqlite database when we developing an app. What is the counterpart in react native? Do I have to use AsyncStorage to store data without a native module?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Updated answer: there's now a fledgling SQLite wrapper available:

https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Previously:

[This comment on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9271491) indicates that there's nothing available right now:

> There is currently no native module for SQLite, but you can build one
>   if you want. :-D
>   http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html
>
> We use a key-value store for most of our client-side persistence:
>   http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

It's by Eric Vicenti who seems to work at Facebook and contribute to React Native, so pretty authoritative.

Comment: I just wrote a basic wrapper for SQLite for React Native, not a lot of feature yet but it's a start: https://github.com/almost/react-native-sqlite

Comment: Check out the full blown SQLite plugin for React Native: https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 14):

Full feature SQLite Plugin for React Native is available here:

https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Version 2.1.0 supports both iOS and Android and the fmk has both plain JS callback and Promise based interfaces.

Answer (score 12):

Realm React Native enables you to efficiently write your app’s model layer in a safe, persisted and fast way. Here’s what it looks like:
See
[Realm React Native](https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-react-native/)
and 
[Docs For Realm](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/)

Answer (score 5):

Embedded persistent or in memory database for react-native
https://github.com/smartdemocracy/react-native-local-mongodb

It's have Performance statistics

- Insert: 10,680 ops/s
- Find: 43,290 ops/s
- Update: 8,000 ops/s
- Remove: 11,750 ops/s

Comment: Beware of the choice of a NoSQL database if the data to be stored is relational.

Comment: Realm also support relations, its well documented too.