# What database can I use with React Native

Tags: react-native

I am creating a movie browsing app with React native and I can't find any suitable driver for any database for React native. Can I use MySQL with RN? What can I use to fetch and store data in RN remotely?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't communicate with a remote DB directly (only with a local one). If you want to persist your data somewhere, you have to use a backend middleware for that.

Comment: And what's the best backend middleware to use for that?

Comment: @AgentZebra I'm not aware about your case so I can't recommend you any particular technology. Probably, you can create a new SO question and people will help you to choose a best fit for your development stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for local database, there is SQLite plugin for RN...

[Look at my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313898/how-can-i-access-local-database-on-react-native/33438122#33438122)