# What local database do I use with React Native?

Tags: database, react-native

I'm new to react native and I need a list of local database tools that will meet the minimum criteria in the description to follow.

If this were a PHP/MySQL application, I build 3 database tables:

```
t_food (500 rows)
- food_id (primary_key)
- food_name (string)

t_meal (100 000 rows)
- meal_id (primary_key)
- meal_name (string)

t_meal_item (1 000 000 rows)
- meal_id (foreign_key)
- food_id (foreign_key)
```

These three tables combined in MySQL takes up about 10MB to 15MB. Then I would use PHP to create an interface that will present the results of this query:

```
SELECT meal_id FROM t_meal_item WHERE food_id = @food1 AND meal_id IN (SELECT meal_id FROM t_meal_item WHERE food_id = @food2 AND meal_id IN (SELECT meal_id FROM t_meal_item WHERE food_id = @food3))
```

In a MySQL/PHP application, the results of the SQL query will return in less than 2 seconds.

In the react-native world, I need a local database that achieves similar results to above but must also comply with the following requirements:

1. must support 15 MB of persistent storage (so that you can use it without internet access)
2. querying for a meal filtered by 3 food items must complete in less than 3 seconds on modern mainstream mobile devices.  Eg. the equivalent of the SQL query above must complete in less than 3 seconds on an iphone 6 and Huawei Nova Plus.

I have already tried the following:

A. Realm is failing on criteria 2 as indicated in this question here:

[Improve the speed of a realm query in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394870/improve-the-speed-of-a-realm-query-in-react-native)

A solution to the Realm question will be an acceptable answer to this question.

B. Six years ago, I tried this with core data on an iOS device.  The iOS device kept crashing due to insufficient memory.

C. I'm trying SQLite Storage but already running into this problem here:

[basic React Native SQLite script returning undefined which causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459063/basic-react-native-sqlite-script-returning-undefined-which-causes-error)

What tools can solve this problem?

Comment: How can I improve the quality of the question such that I don't get close or down votes?  I'm simply asking what are tools normally meant to solve the problem i'm asking.  My problem should be pretty common that there are common approaches to this, as opposed to anything controversial

Comment: I did not downvoted your question or flagged it but I thought it because answer of this question is very much opinion based since every developer has a different approach on data. You have really a lot of choice since you can go with online database like Firebase or Realm (can work offline too) or a traditional like database like SQLlite or even with a static array of data inserted within the app itself. Every each of them has a positive and a negative side and choosing one is pretty much developer's preference.

Comment: @bennygenel thanks that's what i'm looking for, a list of common tools used to solve problem.  Do you konw from experience if the amount of data I'm dealing with will be a problem?  Five years ago, i remember I had performance issues on native iOS trying to deal with a million records in t_meal_item when stored in the iOS model system.  That won't be a problem in any of these newer technologies you mentioned?

Comment: I have never tried to store that much information locally so I can't say anything about that but I can say that in 5 years a lot changed. I think you should do a small test project and test all the options you have and decide it for yourself

Comment: Tool recommendation requests are explicitly off-topic here. See #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I've re-worded the question so that it focuses more on "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is" as described in the /on-topic page you mentioned.

Comment: @charlesduffy, specifically, there are performance requirements that must be met.  And at least one of the options proposed has failed by a substantial margin .  So would like to know from anyone's experience what options I should prioritize in my research.  I want to avoid losing time exploring dead end options

Comment: I'd definitely go for SQLite. I've used it for much larger databases than that -- if you're saying it's "failed by a substantial margin", I'm going to posit that that's likely to be a question of the details of how it was deployed and used (schema design and indexing decisions, &c). (Mind you, my set of personal preferences are such that I'm much happier with Datascript or otherwise something Datalog-based, but I'm not going to advise that to someone who doesn't already know what Datalog is).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks! I'm trying SQLite Storage, if you have any experience with it on React-Native, maybe you'll have insight into this probelm I'm having? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459063/basic-react-native-sqlite-script-returning-undefined-which-causes-error

Comment: Sorry -- when I've used a database in conjunction with React specifically, it's been [Datascript](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript) + [Reagent](http://reagent-project.github.io/). If you're not doing ClojureScript, my experience probably isn't very relevant. (Last time I pushed SQLite really hard, the project was [cscvs](https://launchpad.net/launchpad-cscvs), written in Python; I was one of the earlier maintainers -- taking over from Mark Ferrell and doing performance work -- before it was adopted by Bazaar/Canonical/Launchpad).

Answer (score 10):

consider react native as front end library thats need a restful api to connect so you can make backend with php and react native will receive data from it

if you need local database you can use [react-native-local-mongodb](https://github.com/smartdemocracy/react-native-local-mongodb)

or [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage)

or [react-native-sqlite](https://github.com/almost/react-native-sqlite)

also if you use [redux](http://redux.js.org) you can also use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Comment: I won't have internet access most of the time. So the Restful API won't be useful.

Comment: you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313898/how-can-i-access-local-database-on-react-native

Comment: I updated my question to state the performance requirements.  I already tried realm and despite being praised as one of the fastest db out there for react native, it has already failed my performance requirements by a substantial margin.  Before I evaluate each local db one by one, do you know if any of the options you listed will meet the specified performance requirements? I prefer not to explore dead end options.

Comment: monogodb is fast but it is no sql database sqllite is sql based but less in performance  and ignore redux persist as it work better with small data not large

Comment: thanks, maybe you might have insight into my problem here for sqlite storage? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459063/basic-react-native-sqlite-script-returning-undefined-which-causes-error

Comment: Im trying react-native-local-mongodb and it is not yet reliable. But you're all welcome to  help kill some bugs. It's promising

Answer (score 6):

I have not used those other databases that people listed, but I would recommend Realm.
Very useful, fast, fully integrated with react-native and very well documented.

https://realm.io

Comment: I tried Realm but I'm experiencing performance issues as described in this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394870/improve-the-speed-of-a-realm-query-in-react-native .  Do you know how to improve query speed in realm?  Otherwise, Realm will not be an adequate solution.

Comment: @John for the late response. Have you tried in release mode? In debug mode it's really slow, but when you go to release you don't feel any slowness.

Comment: All real offerings have a cloud component. Am I mistaken? I am looking for local device storage only

Comment: @ManuelHernandez you could do this with realm-js.

Comment: Thank you, but I found out that I was able to set up a decent enough CRUD operation with two arrays of objects, filter, map and persisiting on AsyncStorage. The sample is a little lengthy so its  a gist https://gist.github.com/ConnectedReasoning/262e081e6a8736914507cb5fe02e0a82 if your data needs are simple I'd recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLite, it has a native plugin for React Native :
https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Comment: I updated my question to state the performance requirements. I already tried realm and despite being praised as one of the fastest db out there for react native, it has already failed my performance requirements by a substantial margin.  Do you know if SQLite will meet my performance requirements?  I've read in some blogs that it will not, so don't want to lose time exploring dead options

Comment: @John, used properly, SQLite is really darned fast. The only place (other than concurrency) where it lags behind the big databases is that it doesn't have a heavy-duty query optimizer, but that just means it's on you (the user) to build optimized queries.

Comment: @DanielMedina thanks, do you know how to solve this problem here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459063/basic-react-native-sqlite-script-returning-undefined-which-causes-error

Answer (score 1):

As of now, [WatermelonDB](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB) seems to fulfil both size limit and performance requirements.

Realm is now commercial and tightly coupled to MongoDB and their cloud services (or at least it seems like that from the documentation).

I've also had a quick look at PouchDB, but one of it's react-native integrations [stockulus/pouchdb-react-native](https://github.com/stockulus/pouchdb-react-native) is based on AsyncStorage (which from my experience is terribly slow), and other one [craftzdog/pouchdb-react-native](https://github.com/craftzdog/pouchdb-react-native) is based on sqlite, but has no activity in last few years.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, it totally depends upon the application requirements. If your application is not large scale you can use React Native's default Async Storage, if you are using redux, you can use redux-persist and provide it async storage plugin so it will persist your reducers automatically.

In other case, if you have a large scale application and you are much concerned about the database, you should use **WatermelonDB**, as it is the best available database for React Native. It also provide synchronising functionality through which you can create an online/offline app with database automatically being synced to the backend. WatermelonDB is also using SQlite on its backend to store data but its more powerful and useful