# basic React Native SQLite script returning undefined which causes error

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I'm trying to learn to use react-native-sqlite-storage as described on this page here:

https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

I am working on a windows machine trying to build an android app.  I have the following code:

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';

function errorCB(err) {
  console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
}

function successCB() {
  console.log("SQL executed fine");
}

function openCB() {
  console.log("Database OPENED");
}

var db = SQLite.openDatabase("test.db", "1.0", "Test Database", 200000, openCB, errorCB);
db.transaction((tx) => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Employees a, Departments b WHERE a.department = b.department_id', [], (tx, results) => {
      console.log("Query completed");

    });
});

export default 1;
```

When I run this, I get the error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'NativeModules["SQLite"][method]')

The error is happening on the line `var db = SQLite.openDatabase("test.db", "1.0", "Test Database", 200000, openCB, errorCB);`

I suspect the reason the error is happening is because SQLite expects the existence of a database before you can actually open it.  However, I do not see any instructions in the link above on how to create a database with react-native-sqlite-storage, so I'm not sure if my assumption is correct.  Additionally, I assume I'd need to have a table for Employees, but again, the link above didn't explicitly state examples on how to create one.  SO I don't know if my assumption is correct.

So how do I get SQLite.openDatabase() command to work?

**More information**

I deleted my project. Then I tried to re-install everything again, this time closely following the installation instructions for sqlite storage for android as mentioned on the andpor's github instructions (ie, modifying gradle files, updating MainApplication class etc...).  Once I did that, running the command `react-native run-android` from the CLI causes this build error:

> ERROR  EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\John
>   Lai\Projects\ReactNative\myapp\android\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\myapp\realm\unspecified\jars\classes.jar'
>   {"errno":-4048,"code":"EPERM","syscall":"lstat","path":"C:\Users\John
>   Lai\Projects\ReactNative\myapp\android\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\myapp\realm\unspecified\jars\classes.jar"}
>   Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\John
>   Lai\Projects\ReactNative\myapp\android\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\myapp\realm\unspecified\jars\classes.jar'
>       at Error (native)

I tried running this command as a regular user and as an administrator, and still the same issue.

**More Information 2**

I deleted my project.  Then I did `npm install` for all my projects.  Then I tried the commands `rnpm link` and `react-native link react-native-sqlite-storage`, both of which gave this error:

> ERR! It seems something went wrong while linking. Error: spawn UNKNOWN
>   Please file an issue here: https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm/issues

So now the project won't even build.  Any ideas?

Comment: From the error, this looks more like a problem with the way the module is being imported, rather than the function being successfully invoked and misbehaving subsequently. Which is to say, I suspect Mohamed has the right of it.

Comment: So, `lstat` is a request to get metadata for a symlink. Windows doesn't have proper symlinks, so I'm not surprised this fails. Do you have a proper UNIX box you can work on?

Comment: (You might also report a Windows portability bug to whichever product provided the build-process code running that `lstat`).

Comment: ah man, that's irritating....all my linux machines are headless since I use them mostly for web dev.  Ok, i'll spend time to spin off an ubuntu or something...

Comment: are you sure that the error came from react-native-sqlite-storage not realm i can see realm in your path also you can use bash for windows instead of cmd

Comment: did you set up the project manually per instructions or tried automatic linking...manual setup works well 99% of the time...automatic linking fails frequently...

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the library is not linked 
to link they suggest two ways

- with pod (advanced)
- with `rnpm link` (easy) but this command is deprecated

so to link the library you should use the

`react-native link react-native-sqlite-storage`

this command is equal to `rnpm link` but not deprecated

if automatic build failing try with manual linking for iOS [manually linking ios](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#step-1a-if-rnpm-link-does-not-work-for-you-you-can-try-manually-linking-according-to-the-instructions-below) and android [manually linking android](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#how-to-use-android)

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, I ran the react-native link `react-native-sqlite-storage` command and got this error `rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: spawn UNKNOWN` .  I tried looking through google for this issue and see it is a generic issue.  And no one has yet commented on this issue happening to sqlite storage. Any ideas?

Comment: I also added more information to my question because I just tried to reset and re-build the project.

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: when the link failed did you try manual linking i'll update my answer

Comment: both the rnpm link command and react-native link react-native-sqlite-storage gave this error: `rnpm-link ERR! It seems something went wrong while linking. Error: spawn UNKNOWN
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm/issues`

Comment: see this for iOS https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#step-1a-if-rnpm-link-does-not-work-for-you-you-can-try-manually-linking-according-to-the-instructions-below

Comment: I'm building android app on a windows, so ios and mac instructions should not be relevant to me right?

Comment: and for android https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#step-1---npm-install

Comment: because this error  ERROR EPERM: operation not permitted run command as administrator from your terminal

Comment: I updated my answer to show both your latest suggestions produced the same errors still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155621/discussion-between-mohamed-khalil-and-john).

Comment: it shows me somthing like this:- rnpm-install info Platform 'ios' module react-native-sqlite-storage is already linked

Comment: @DeepakChawla this is old answer you should navigate to ios folder and run pod install

Comment: i have some issues with the sqlite in react native, can you help me please ?

Comment: @shira how can I help

Comment: i have the insert update and delete functions with sqlite but it doesnt work for me , do you have facebook or something else that i can connect with you coz i must someone that know the sqlite coz i am new with that .

Comment: @shira I think it is better to post a new question with your problem so any one who is good at this will answer

Comment: I did it already :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62776370/react-native-there-is-way-to-insert-update-and-delete-data-from-my-db-file

Comment: @shira sorry I don't have an answer for this question hope you found one soon

Answer (score 0):

lstat command error is generating on windows due to permission issues or npm version issues.

You can do 2 things to pass this.
1.Open terminal in admin mode . 
2.upgrade/degrade npm version

For plugin installation, configure  manually

Answer (score 0):

You need change MainApplication.java with:

import org.pgsqlite.SQLitePluginPackage;

and

in getPackages:

new SQLitePluginPackage()