# React Native SQLite script returning error: undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, sqlite

This is a pretty basic React Native app I am making with Expo CLI. I already have a populated SQL Database called (I know this is a bad name) pythonsqlite.db with a table Users that I am trying to query using [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage).

One of my screens has a button with an onPress function that querys the database for all users:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Button, Picker } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
//import { openDatabase } from "expo-sqlite";
import { openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
//import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
//import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
//import {Asset} from "expo-asset";


const CharacterCreateScreen = ({navigation, route}) =>{
  return(
    <View style={styles2.container}>
      <Text>Sad :(</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => dbCall()}
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', marginRight:30 }}>
          <Text>Button</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  )
}


  function dbCall(){
  function errorCB(err) {
      console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
    }
    
    function successCB() {
      console.log("SQL executed fine");
    }
    
    function openCB() {
      console.log("Database OPENED");
    }


   var db = SQLite.openDatabase("pythonsqlite.db", "1.0", "Test Database", 200000, openCB, errorCB);

    var userQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users";

    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(userQuery, [], (error, results) => { //callback function to handle the results
        alert("Query Completed.");
        //alert(results);
        // Get rows with Web SQL Database spec compliance.
        var len = results.rows.length;
        alert(len);
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          let row = results.rows.item(i);
          arr1.push(results.rows.item(i));
          alert(`User name: ${row.userName}`);
        }
      });
    }); //alert("Done.");
  }
```

However upon pressing the button I get this error message on my IOS device:
[image]

I tried running this command as is stated [on this page](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage):

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

I bash I got this error:

```
bash: cd: ios: No such file or directory
```

In Windows Powershell:

```
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
```

This is where I am stuck. I'm not exactly sure where to go. This is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459063/basic-react-native-sqlite-script-returning-undefined-which-causes-error), but it is 3 years old and doesn't seem to be answered. I've been trying to figure this out for a really long time if anyone could help me that would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { SQLite } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
```

should be

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
```

`SQLite` is exported as a default export ... not a named export.

**Edit**

The new error means the module is not linked properly...

If you're using ReactNative 0.60 and above Run `cd ios && pod install && cd ..` ... Linking is not required in React Native 0.60 and above

if lower than that ... you'll have to [follow the steps in this link](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#ios)

Comment: This is interesting. I will try this when I get home from work and let you know what happens.

Comment: This changed the error message but did not fix the problem. I have updated the question to reflect the new error message although it is very similar.

Comment: Using React Native version 0.62.2. In bash running the above command returns ios no such file or directory. Windows PowerShell returns && is not a valid operator. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the managed workflow in expo, right? If so, you should be following the example [here](https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/master/with-sqlite/App.js) and using the `expo-sqlite` package and not the `react-native-sqlite-storage` directly.

```
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";
// later in the file 
var db = SQLite.openDatabase("pythonsqlite.db", /* other args */);
```

If you're using the bare workflow, or this still doesn't work, then I'll have to take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

So easy (in my lucky case!)..., changing:

`import { SQLite } from "expo-sqlite";`

to

`import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";`

fixed the error for me.