# Offline database in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

My users will be storing 10-500 records locally. I'm looking for a database with an offline-first approach that works with Expo.

Eventually the user will have the option to sync the data to an (undecided) online service. Looking for suggestions for this as well.

Users should be able to register an account to use online functionality such as syncing their data, uploading photos and viewing other users content. Offline functionality should work even without an account.

What are your suggestions for a database layer and the stack in general? Hoping to hear your suggestions.

Comment: There are some solutions mentioned already that you can try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327412/what-local-database-do-i-use-with-react-native

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What local database do I use with React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327412/what-local-database-do-i-use-with-react-native)

Comment: Expo comes with an SQLite DB https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Bruno Eduardo on the comments Expo comes with sqlite.
An example:
You import SQLite from expo:

```
import { SQLite } from 'expo';
```

You then can initiate a database like so:

```
const db = SQLite.openDatabase('db.db');
```

This would create the database in the local users phone.
From there you can query the tables you'd like to create and load with data like so.

```
db.transaction(tx => {
tx.executeSql('create table if not exists users (id integer);')
});
```

There are two approaches you can take (probably more but just two I'm thinking of).
You can query the data from an api so that it'll load it locally.  Or the other option would be to copy a database with your data already setup to the device.

I need to mention there's a few problems with your approach.  Best practice for many reasons, which I won't mention, is to use an api for data.  If you're dealing with simple records the time to query an api is minimal.  If the user is "Eventually the user will have the option to sync the data" then it might be best to consider working that out before you begin to build a local db.